# I want to add different different color for option show more link in react-big-calendar

Tags: reactjs, calendar, react-big-calendar

[image]

I want to add  different different color for option show more link in react-big-calendar

Answer (score 0):

You can use messages prop to Calendar component.

```
<Calendar
...other props
messages={{
         ...other messages
         showMore: (total) => (<span style={{color: 'red'}}>+{total} more</span>)
}}
/>
```